# Counting substring in a string, excluding one string

Tags: python

I am trying to count "dog" in a string, excluding "doggy".
For example: "dogs, doghouse" counts 2. "doggy, dog" counts 1

Comment: dogs_only = dog.count("dog") - doggy = dog.count("doggy"). This worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = 'doggy dog'
s.count('dog') - s.count('doggy') == 1
```

Answer (score 4):

The following regex will match every occurance of `dog` that is not followed by `gy`

```
dog(?!gy)
```

You can use `re.findall` and then count the results

```
len(re.findall(r'dog(?!gy)', string))
```